# Choque de validaciones VeeValidate

Tags: vue.js, validación, veevalidate

Necesito poder escribir letras, espacios y números en el mismo `input`, utilizando VeeValidate para validar, solo toma en cuenta una de las dos validaciones, es decir aplico las validaciones `alpha_spaces` y `alpha_num` pero solo toma en cuenta una dependiendo de lo que se escriba en el input.

Un ejemplo para que me entiendan mejor:

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate, {locale: 'es'});
var app = new Vue({
 el: "#root",
 data: {
    datos: {},
 },

 mounted: function(){
  
 },

 methods: {
  Validar: function(){
    app.$validator.validateAll("formulario").then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          swal( {title:"Éxito!", text:"Validación correcta!", icon:"success", button:"Aceptar", closeOnClickOutside:false}); 
        }else {
          swal( {title:"Información!", text:"Verifique los campos nuevamente!", icon:"info", button:"Aceptar", closeOnClickOutside:false}); 
        }
   });
  },
 }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@latest/dist/vee-validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@latest/dist/locale/es.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="root">
  <br><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Test"
        data-vv-scope="formulario" data-vv-name="test" v-validate="'required|alpha_spaces|alpha_num'" v-model="datos.campo_uno">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <a class="btn btn-default" v-on:click="Validar();">Aceptar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a>
        </span>
      </div><!-- /input-group -->
      <p class="font-red" v-show="errors.has('formulario.test')">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span> <i class="fa fa-warning font-red"></i> {{ errors.first('formulario.test') }} 
      </p>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
  </div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: pudiste solucionar el problema? como?

Comment: pues... sinceramente en ya mi ultima opción de hacerlo porque no tenia mas tiempo, modifique directamente el archivo de VeeValidate para que admitiera los caracteres que necesitaba... el arreglo alpa_spaces y eso, le agrege lo que necesitaba que aceptara